# Can i use a Graph-Algorithm on Yed-Graphs with python?

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, editor

I am using Yed to paint some graphs as shown in the picture below. Is there a way I can use python to compute a Depth-First exploration on these? 
I would like the algorithm to protocol the Edges he has traveled and the nodes he visited.

Example graph:
[image: example graph]

Edit:
I would like to use this method to record actions of people in a sports game. At first you start at a base/Root, then you can run or jump (c or d). Running brings you to point 2, jumping to point 5. 
The result that I need then is:

```
1.  root, ([c,2] ,[b,3]), Descript_3 
2.  root, ([c,2] ,[a,4]), Descript_4
3.  root, ([c,2] ,[b,2], [a,4]), Descript_4
...
```

I am just using yed, so I can use a graphical interface. If there is something better in pure python, I am all up for it. But lets stick to yed for now. Can I get additional attributes to the nodes?

Edit:
Since I cannot get this thing to work for myself, I am setting a bounty for an example program. The example program should do the following:

```
1. Parse the graphml-File and build up the tree
2. Compute all Roundtrip-Path with Node-Coverage
3. write all paths into a table: Name of the node, Text on the arrow
```

From there I can figure the rest out myself. If its done by using librarys, then that's cool too, but I need to be able to extend it myself. I would also have it to be able to handle graphs, instead of trees.

Comment: The path is supposed to go from root to 2, from 2 to 4. The edges that lead there are named : c,a. So yes you are right, this is a typo. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use the networkx module (need to be installed `pip install networkx`). This module is a powerfull library for working with graphs. It can read the graphml format which yed produces and has algorithems for traversing a graph. Have a look at the documentation of it: [networkx](http://networkx.github.io/)

Comment: @Micheled'Amico Wrong, networkx can read the lables. You just have to explisitly ask the `edges` or `nodes` methode of the graph object to include the data in the output (call it with `data=True`).

Comment: @Micheled'Amico Can you post the graphml file.

Comment: Strange! I can reproduce your observation with **your** file. On the other hand I have created the same graph with yEd version 3.13 and I can see the node lables in networkx too. The main difference is that the nodetype is `<y:ShapeNode>` and in your example it is `<y:GenericNode configuration="com.yworks.flowchart.terminator">`.

Comment: Is there also a version for windows?

Comment: The module `networkx` works on windows as well as linux. Installation is described here: http://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9.1/install.html